# Find real intervals where a function is nearly constant

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, numerical-methods, algorithms

A differentiable function $f$ is said to be nearly constant over $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ if $f$ does not vary much over $I$. For example, one can ask for >0 small enough such that $\displaystyle \int_{I} (f(x)-\lambda_I)^2 \, \mathrm{d}\mu(x) < \epsilon$  with $\lambda_I = \frac{1}{\mu(I)} \int_{I} f(x)\,d\mu(x)$.

Does anyone know if there is an article or page that discusses how to find these $I$ intervals for a given $\epsilon$ threshold?
More generally I am looking for a (numerical) analysis method that would allow me to know if sometimes a function $f$ is almost constant.

Thanks in advance!